# Hough Lines Detection inconsistent from frame to frame

Tags: opencv, hough-transform, canny-operator

The HOUGH lines (RED and WHITE) I get vary from one frame of video to the next even though the scene is static.

There is also lots of variation in the Canny results from frame to frame. This problem is not so bad here with my test case but for a real street scene, the Canny detected edges really go nuts from frame to frame.

As can be seen, many lines also simply get missed.

I realize that the noise is different from frame to frame but the conversion to grayscale and subsequent blur make the input images very close (at least to my eye).

What is going on and is there any way to fix this?

[image: Same Scene - Different Results]

```
# Python 2/3 compatibility
import sys
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3

if PY3:
    xrange = range

import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from time import sleep

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    SLOPE = 2.0

    while(True):

        sleep(0.2)

        ret, src = cap.read()
        gray            = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray_blur       = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
        gray_blur_canny = cv2.Canny(gray_blur,  25, 150)

        cv2.imshow("src", src)
        cv2.imshow("gray_blur", gray_blur)
        cv2.imshow("gray_blur_canny", gray_blur_canny)

        cimg = src.copy() # numpy function

        lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
                    gray_blur_canny, 
                    1, 
                    math.pi/180.0, 
                    40, 
                    np.array([]), 
                    50, 
                    10)
        if lines is not None:
            a,b,c = lines.shape
            for i in range(a):
                numer = lines[i][0][3] - lines[i][0][1] + 0.001;
                denom = lines[i][0][2] - lines[i][0][0];
                if (denom == 0):
                    denom = 0.001;
                slope = abs(numer/denom);
                print slope
                if (slope > SLOPE):
                        cv2.line(
                            cimg, 
                            (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), 
                            (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), 
                            (0, 0, 255), 
                            3, 
                            cv2.LINE_AA)
                if (slope < (1.0/SLOPE)):
                        cv2.line(
                            cimg, 
                            (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), 
                            (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), 
                            (200, 200, 200), 
                            3, 
                            cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow("hough lines", cimg)
        ch = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if ch == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You can get different results even on the same frame. The `P` in `HoughLinesP` stands for probabilistic. Not all values are tested for, and the ones that are, are selected randomly. But you should be able to get *more* results than that either way and should be able to get a significant amount of overlap. Dilating your binary image might help get some more hits in the hough result. You can also try different `rho` and `theta` parameters for the `HoughLinesP()` method.

Comment: try lineSegmentDetector instead, it produces quite consistent results  (but because of noise, most methods can be a bit inconsistent).